# Is it possible to get the rewrite logs in a custom log file in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, rewritelog

I am using **Apache 2.4** and using below code-

```
CustomLog logs/rewrite_test.log common
```

and it is giving me logs something like this-

```
8.38.28.983 stage.mysite.test.com- [10/Aug/2017:16:01:19 -0400] "GET /etc/designs/sites/clientlibs/assets/css/plugins/awesome/fonts/font-webfont.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 404 13887
```

I need to have **rewrite logs** in the **rewrite_test.log** file. Is it possible in apache 2.4?

In **apache 2.2** we were using-

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite_test.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 1
```

Comment: Sure, you can use your syslog deamon (typically `rsyslog` these days) to filter and channel the entries.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. I am very new to this. Do you have any code sample for the same?

Comment: Well, just take a look into the existing file rules in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`. That should give you a good start.